# Hibernate: typecasting of proxies

Tags: hibernate, orm, jboss

They say in the [Hibernate Reference Documentation (21.1.3. Single-ended association proxies)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-proxies):

> By choosing lazy="no-proxy" instead of the default lazy="proxy", you
>   can avoid problems associated with typecasting.

Could you explain why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `lazy` is `proxy`, the association field in question is initialized with a proxy object. Since the actual type of associated object is not known when proxy is created, this proxy, obviously, cannot be casted to it.

When `lazy` is `no-proxy`, the field is not initialized. Instead, access to that field is intercepted and the actual object is loaded when you try to access the field. This interception requires bytecode instrumentation.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. I am just wondering: in the `lazy=no-proxy` case, if there is no proxy, then in which Java object the id of the associated object is stored (before the actual associated object is loaded)?

Comment: @rapt: I guess it's stored inside an object that contains association field. An additional field to store that id can be added during bytecode instrumentation.